# X0 does not exist in the directory for wine

Tags: ubuntu, x11, wine

```
winecfg
connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory
Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.
kami@Misaka:~$ cd /tmp/.X11-unix
kami@Misaka:/tmp/.X11-unix$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 4096 Dec 26 10:04 .
drwxrwxrwt 5 root root 4096 Dec 26 10:41 ..
kami@Misaka:/tmp/.X11-unix$
```

what i have done so far

i installed wine

when i tried to run winecfg i got the error that X0 doesn't exist so i went to the directory /tmp/.X11-unix/ to see if it existed and as you can see it doesn't

is there a way to fix this i'm trying to run a windows application over wine with ssh X11 protocal

also i've tried setting the display this does not help because the file or directory X0 does not exist at all on my server under the directory /tmp/.X11-unix

also i have restarted several times it does not come back

Comment: sorry bout that >.>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first i was attempting to load an executable through wine and started having this issue the guide by Extricate from here gave me my answer
http://forum.coldbird.net/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=1714

> This might be of interest for some of the more frugal hosts. I'm currently running an Area Server from an Ubuntu VPS with no graphics capabilities and only 128mb of ram (quite far below the minimum requirements  :lol: ). It's certainly cheaper than buying a windows server or hosting from home.
>
> First things first this guide is for Ubuntu, I will assume you already have a folder set up on your server with the Area Server files in, before you transfer it to your server you must make sure it is set to run fullscreen mode via the television shaped button on the Area Server menu.
>   You will also need to install Xpra on your home computer, on Windows it's as easy as downloading it from their website and then running it.
>
> You will need Screen, Xvfb, Xpra Wine and the X fonts, install them:
>
> sudo apt-get install screen
>
> sudo apt-get install Xvfb
>
> sudo apt-get install xpra
>
> sudo apt-get install wine
>
> sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic
>
> Next up we have to start Xvfb, for my toaster of a server I ran at 800x600, but if you are rich and have cpu cycles to burn go for whatever it is you want.
>
> Open up a new screen by typing "screen"
>
> then type "Xvfb -screen 10 800x600x16"
>
> If all has gone well, detach from that screen by pressing ctrl +a and then ctrl + d
>
> Open up another new screen by typing "screen" again, now we are going to start an Xpra server
>
> type "xpra start :10"
>
> Good, now start Xpra on your home computer. You should see a screen like this:
>   [xpra example http://puu.sh/aLbqT/d18cbd1331.png](http://puu.sh/aLbqT/d18cbd1331.png)
>
> Enter your host's information and press connect.
>
> Back on your server you need to set up wine,
>
> wget http://kegel.com/wine/winetricks
>
> sh winetricks d3dx9
>
> then type "DISPLAY=:10 winecfg"
>
> On  your home computer you should see a pop up of the winecfg screen. Set it to Windows 2000 compatibility and press Apply then Ok. It should close.
>
> Finally type "DISPLAY=:10 wine "AREA SERVER.exe"
>
> On your home computer should see a pop up containing the area server. Be patient, the window may be slow to react. From here connect as normal.
>
> Once it is running select the tray icon of Xpra on your home computer and disconnect. In the server terminal press ctrl +a and then ctrl + d.
>
> That is all.